# how to get String/character value from key Code;

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard

I am using an input tag of html which is supposed to work similar to input of google search.

```
function onKeyPressFun(event){
    var inputObj = document.getElementById("tagInput");
    var strTags = inputObj.value + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    alert("post data: strTags" + strTags);
}
```

I want to send the data to server to detect if any tag starting with this substring exist.

I want to add the character/string (whichever works here) from keyPress event to the existing input in the text. 

As in the code above I used String.fromCharCode. When I press 'b' I found keyCode 0 and the value of String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) was nothing; neither a blank.

Any fix for this?

Comment: "When I press 'b' I found keyCode 0" - please reproduce that on jsfiddle

Comment: Won't this be useless on keyboards that aren't your desired layout?

Comment: There is no universal mapping between `keyCode`s and `charCode`s, for obvious reasons. See @WTK's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may have something to do with support for `.keyCode` property across different browsers. Normalize keyCode value to get better results. One way to do it (part in parentheses is from jQuery source):

```
// e.g.
String.fromCharCode(event.charCode != null ? event.charCode : event.keyCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
String.fromCharCode(event.which); // it works in all major browsers
```