# Reliable way to get value of keyEvent for "all" browsers including Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, mobile-browser

I'm trying to get the value of the keyPressed in either a `keyPress`, `keydown`, or `keyUp` event. 
The different solutions here works well on Chrome, FireFox, IE etc. However they fail on android devices.

I tried several solutions inspired from the following SO:

- [Get Character value from KeyCode in JavaScript... then trim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772179/get-character-value-from-keycode-in-javascript-then-trim)
- [How to convert keycode to character using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977792/how-to-convert-keycode-to-character-using-javascript)
- [how to get String/character value from key Code;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258929/how-to-get-string-character-value-from-key-code)

First Solution:

```
element.keydown(function (e) { 
    var keyCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    var digit = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

    // here digit is "å" on android using danish locale
}
```

KeyUp yields same result.
KeyPressed will not fire on chrome on android.

To reproduce i made a plunkr, which shows the behaviour:

https://plnkr.co/BVUfiJrBr0RBPDst9izD/

It works fine on desktop but the keyCode is always `229` on android browsers, regardless of the key pressed.

I reproduced the error on:

- Samsung Galaxy S6, Android 5.1.1, Browser: Chrome 48.0.2564.95
- Sony Experia Z2, Android 5.1.1, Browser: Chrome 48.0.2564.95

It did work on:

- Samsung Galaxy S6, Android 5.1.1, Browser: Firefox
- Iphone

Trying to reproduce the error indicates a bug in Chrome. Is there a different way around this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture keys typed on android virtual keyboard using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743490/capture-keys-typed-on-android-virtual-keyboard-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`input`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input-input) event? Faced a similar problem once and that helped me back in the day with Android 4.4 (Worked in FF, Chrome and Android's native browser).

Made a small example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2r2nzov/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. It returns the same char for every type of input.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to solve this myself.  In my case, the element is a text input element.  On the keyup event (which fires in all browsers), I blur the input.  Now whatever was entered is available in the input.val() and the change event fires.  So I add a function on the change event on the input that collects what was entered and returns focus to the input.  In my case, I only needed to get a single character.  I haven't tested this with a situation where someone is typing quickly and the browser has to execute all of this between rapid keystrokes.

My code looks like this:

```
$('input').on( 'keyup', function(){
    $(this).blur();
});
$('input').on( 'change', function(){
    // my code to do what I want with the value that was entered,
    // which thanks to the blur() I can get from input.val()
    $(this).focus(); // return focus to the input so the user can continue
});
```

Maybe this will help?